# RxJS: How can I event.preventDefault() a drop event?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

My markup:

```
<section id="drop-target">
  Drop file here...
</section>
```

My code:

```
var dropTarget = document.getElementById('drop-target');

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dropTarget, 'dragover').subscribe(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

var dropStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dropTarget, 'drop');

dropStream.subscribe(function(event) {
  console.log('This will be called.');
  event.preventDefault();
});

dropStream.map(function(event) {
  console.log('This will not be called.');
  return event.dataTransfer.files[0].path;
});
```

Any ideas how my last `map`callback can be called? I need both `preventDefault`s for `drop` and `dragover` to prevent the browser from opening the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to subscribe to your `map` stream.  All `map` does is create a new observable that will run the `map` operation on the stream.  But you still need to subscribe to make it do something:

```
dropStream
    .map(function (event) {
        console.log("hello");
        return event.dataTransfer.files[0].path;
    })
    .subscribe(function (path) {
        console.log("path=" + path);
    });
```